# jquery - how to change div text after form submit

Tags: jquery

i have a form to enter directions  and display a google map

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="setDirections(this.from.value, 'address', 'en_US'); return false">
```

Outside the form i have the following:

```
Formatted Directions<div id="printdirec"><a href="http://maps.google.com/">Print Directions</a></div>
```

i want to change the value inside the div tag 'printdirec' to say something else

i tried this (which i thought would work) but it doesn't:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $(":submit").click(function(e) {
                $('div.printdirec').val('tttt')
            });

        });
</script>
```

any suggestions of what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The # symbol identifies the ID of the element. Use .text() to set the inner text.

```
$('div#printdirec').text('tttt');
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be more reliable to handle the `submit` event, which gives this:

```
$("form#id-of-your-form").submit(function(e) {
    $('#printdirec').html('tttt');
});
```

See [Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) for basic selector syntax. A quick read-through should eliminate an further confusion as to how to correctly address elements.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$('div.printdirec').val('tttt')
```

is looking for any divs with the **class** of `printdirec`.  You'll want to refer to it by **id**.  Also, you'll want to set the text of the div, not the value.  Try this:

```
$('#printdirec').text('tttt');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div#printdirec").html("tttt");
```

You really should bring all of your submit-logic into the same location. No need to have it in the markup.